# What are the significant differences between tracepath and traceroute?

Tags: networking, traceroute

I recently read a bit of an article on HowToGeek that has me scratching my head a little.  I've got fairly little experience with Linux though, so forgive me if this is entry-level:

> "The tracepath command is similar to traceroute, but it doesn’t require root privileges."
>
> http://www.howtogeek.com/108511/how-to-work-with-the-network-from-the-linux-terminal-11-commands-you-need-to-know/

How do traceroute and tracepath perform a similar function, differently?

What does traceroute do, which requires root privileges, that tracepath doesn't?

Are there scenarios where one should prefer tracepath over traceroute, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

## How do traceroute and tracepath perform a similar function, differently?

Both programs essentially do one thing: send and receive certain IP packets.

A program can use the normal sockets API to do this, or it can manipulate the raw packets from the interface. The sockets API does not require root privileges, because it is fairly secure. There are mechanisms built in to prevent one program from accessing IP packets that another program made.

Tracepath uses the sockets API for all its functionality. Traceroute manipulates raw packets for some of its functionality.

## What does traceroute do, which requires root privileges, that tracepath doesn't?

It manipulates raw packets.

To manipulate raw packets, you need root privileges because by doing this, you bypass the security mechanisms of the sockets API. You gain access to communications of all other processes and users using that interface. Just think about what a virus could do if it could manipulate raw packets.

## Are there scenarios where one should prefer tracepath over traceroute, or vice-versa?

> One advanced command available in Traceroute is the ability to run a
> network trace using IPv4 or IPv6 protocol. It is also possible to
> choose between ICMP, TCP or UDP data formats for a probe. Traceroute
> can choose specific source routings for the probe and choose what port
> to send from. It can set limits on the minimum and maximum TTL to
> accept from an outbound probe. IN addition, Traceroute can show the
> wait time for response pings as well as set how many packets are send
> in each probe and how many probes to send. Some of these commands may
> not be supported by networking hardware along the path, which could
> terminate the probe before it reaches its target destination.

**sources:**
[1](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/differences-between-traceroute-tracepath)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76988/how-is-it-possible-to-run-a-traceroute-like-program-without-needing-root-privile)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772068/raw-socket-access-as-normal-user-on-linux-2-4)

Comment: Finally, an answer with a legitimate security concern that affects the local system. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You can use `traceroute` for advanced network tracing , you can choose between IPv4 and Ipv6 protocols , you can also choose between ICMP, TCP or UDP data formats for a probe.

So `traceroute` has more advanced options than `tracepath` which uses UDP packets for tracing.

Now about **superuser privileges**  :

you can use `traceroute` with both a normal user and a superuser that depends on the **option** you want to use , here is an example :

[image]

Here we are using **UDP** packets which doesn't need superuser privileges

[image]

Here we are using **ICMP** echo packets which need privileges .

By **ICMP** packets you can make DDOS attack.

To learn about ICMP options [Traceroute Man Page](http://ss64.com/bash/traceroute.html)

To view `traceroute` options type in terminal `man traceroute`

ICMP need super user privileges , to ensure just administrators can use some of its options , because it can be used to make ping of death and collecting information about a specific network , the privilege here will give the super user the ability to change options using ICMP packets.

That you can see it , when you try to ping so websites like `www.microsoft.com` , your ping will fail even its online, and that because Microsoft routers block ICMP_requests .

So linux protect the system from unprivileged user , so they can not use this commands for attacking .

Comment: Typically, restrictions against unprivileged users are used to protect the system from *being attacked* - not from being used as a vector for attacking other systems. This doesn't quite make sense to me - do you know of any documentation that backs this up?

Answer (score 4):

i think you have to read this
http://www.ehow.com/list_7526520_differences-between-traceroute-tracepath.html

From the above link:

> **TracePath**
>
> Tracepath traces a path to a designated network address, reporting on the "time to live" or TTL lag and maximum transmission units (MTU) along the way. This command can be run by any user other with access to the command line prompt.

---

> **Traceroute Basics**
>
> Traceroute is essentially the same as Tracepath except that by default, it will only give the TTL value. If you want additional data, you must request those variables on the command line. Also, traceroute requires superuser access to run the command on a Linux box, and some advanced data requests may not be supported by all of the routers along the path. In a Windows environment, any user with access to the command line can run Traceroute.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but could you put some actual content in your answer?

Comment: Hi bodhi.zazen , thank you for improving my post . :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  However, the answer here (haven't gotten to review the link yet) is still missing two parts of the question:  *Why* does `traceroute` require superuser access (especially since it actually seems it does *less* than `tracepath` by default)?  And, aside from scenarios where you're *not* a superuser, why should you choose one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

`ping` and `traceroute` use the ICMP protocol. Like UDP and TCP this is accessible through the normal sockets API. Only UDP and TCP port numbers less than 1024 are protected from use, other than by root. ICMP is freely available to all users.

If you really want to see how ping and traceroute work you can download an example C code implementation for them from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Ping_and_Traceroute.aspx).

In short, they simple open an ICMP socket, and traceroute alters the increments the TTL using setsockopt until the target is reached.

Source : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76988/how-is-it-possible-to-run-a-traceroute-like-program-without-needing-root-privile)

Comment: Also; tracepath uses UDP which -in addition to UDP options in traceroute itself, doesn't require elevated privileges.